# Loop to describe contents of database table

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a overview of a table schema and find areas of improvement.

```
list_columns = reporting.columns.tolist()

description = []
x = 0
for x in list_columns:
    description.append(reporting[x].describe())
    x=x+1
```

This is my current method - it is failing as the description method returns something unable to be collated into a list or dict.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you trying to describe the schema or a table? If you describe the schema, then system tables would be more useful. This would be done with sql like: "select distinct table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'schema_name' and table_type like 'BASE_TABLE'" - depending on your SQL flavour. If you describe the singular table, then you should have all you need in the data frame (if you use pandas as tagged), which would be datatypes and column names.

Comment: I am trying to do both I suppose.

The database is already set up, and I want to show how it is currently working, based on the schema, to improve the schema.

If I could show the schema's efficiency more easily that would be good!

Comment: Which database tech are you using? What do you mean by efficiency?

Comment: Postgresql

By efficiency. We have a lot of categorisations that are used in reporting functions. They weren't really planned, and so a column in a table can have multiple string values, while referring to something another value might. There are also columns that say the same thing as other columns, and generally very little separation of tables for grouping related data sets. So I want to begin showing this is the case visually and give some structure to how to improve this as an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Describing a table with pandas

If you read the table with pandas functions(for example here https://medium.com/@amirziai/query-your-database-over-an-ssh-tunnel-with-pandas-603ce49b35a1 and code is here https://gist.github.com/amirziai/9cc792e41d3241a17a18), you should get as an output a dataframe, that has correct column names and datatypes defined.

Then you can access these by simply(following the gist notation)

```
print(df.dtypes)
print(df.columns)
```

another useful pandas function is value_counts() that would show the insides and for example categorical values and their frequencies nicely:

```
print(df['Pclass'].value_counts())
```

### Describing schema with SQL

If you want to describe multiple tables then you should query the system table called information_schema, which would provide identical data for the whole schema.

```
SELECT 
   table_name, 
   column_name, 
   data_type 
FROM 
   information_schema.columns
WHERE 
   table_name = 'city';
```

Comment: Thanks for this paloman.

I'm particularly interested in fixing the loop in my question, as I am okay with using value_counts(), .dtypes etc, but want to try and create a picture fo each column in a given table.